# Install Ubuntu ARM on headless Marvell Armada 375

Tags: 16.04, arm, netinstall

I have a headless NAS with Marvell Armada 375 dual core ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l). NAS has one Ethernet and one USB port.

I would like to install Ubuntu Server for ARM.

I have prepared as USB with initrd.gz and vmlinuz from Ubuntu netboot [armhf (generic, generic-lpae) - For 32-bit ARM (ARMv7)](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-updates/main/installer-armhf/current/images/generic-lpae/netboot/), pluged the usb in the NAS port, ethernet and powered on the device.

I could not find the device on tftpd let alone install.

Any suggestions